# Materialized view in other user/schema - insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle12c

I am trying to create a materialized view in user user_a.
User user_a has a role assigned to it, role_a.
role_a has privileges -

```
create any table
create any materialized view
select any table.
```

I am getting insufficient privileges when I try to create a materialized view from user_a, into another user, say user_b.

Example:
As user_a -

```
create materialized view user_b.m_v_1 as select * from user_b.table_1;
```

The above statement returns -

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Appreciate if anyone has faced same or know that its an expected behaviour can share information.

Comment: In general, materialized views should only be created by the actual owner of the materialized view. Supporting objects, like Oracle Scheduler programs to control the refresh, are also created that won't be owned by the MV owner if the MV is created by someone else: you will create a dependency between the schemas that could break the MV later (voice of experience talking).

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

It says which privilege user should have in order to create MV.
To create a materialized view in another user's schema:

You must have the CREATE ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW system privilege.

The owner of the materialized view must have the CREATE TABLE system privilege. The owner must also have access to any master tables of the materialized view that the schema owner does not own (for example, if the master tables are on a remote database) and to any materialized view logs defined on those master tables, either through a SELECT object privilege on each of the tables or through the SELECT ANY TABLE system privilege.